# Using SSO while an app is still in development?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I'm new to iOS development. Is there anyway to get FB SSO working with an app without an Apple Store ID? Or is there a way to get an apple store id for development purposes? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to have submitted the app to apple to use SSO - i've tested SSO apps using the emulator, etc

Comment: How did you get safari (on simulator) and the facebook app (on device) to return to your application once the authentication process was completed?

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso - i used the sample app that comes with the SDK and all i needed to do was change the app ID in two places (one of which is the URL Scheme needed for the SSO to work - which is likely to be your problem if you followed the other parts of the docs)

Comment: Cool thanks... i actually realized while checking my plist to the samples that the sample appended fb to the front of it's ID in the URL Schemes.